# Why does pandas turn 1 column into a series? new to Python

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen answers to this, none that I could get my head around, I have two questions, just looking to understand why this is the case and when that is useful?

Comment: 1- this assumption is incorrect: "*each column in a data frame seem to be dictionaries in a dictionary*". 2- the rest of the question is unclear

Comment: doc: [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#dataframe): `"You can think of it like a spreadsheet or SQL table, or a dict of Series objects."` So maybe there is nothing to change but simply it gets Series directly.

Comment: if you use single column - `df[column]` - then you get `Series`, but if you use list with single column - `df[ [column] ]` - then you get `DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

1D array is a series . Series contain data of only one column.
And data with more than 1D array is a dataframe.